# find line with repetitive pattern

Tags: grep

I have a log file like this

```
123.123.123.123 (456.456.456.456) abc def .....
123.123.123.123 (123.123.123.123) abc def .....
123.123.123.123 (456.456.456.456) abc def .....
455.455.455.455 (456.456.456.456) abc def .....
555.555.555.555 (555.555.555.555) efc bbb .....
```

in some lines, the IP outside the brackets is the same as inside, I want to output those lines:

```
123.123.123.123 (123.123.123.123) abc def .....
555.555.555.555 (555.555.555.555) efc bbb .....
```

how can I do this with grep or sed ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Care to share it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a *backreference* to a numbered *capture group*:

```
$ grep '\([0-9.]*\) (\1)' file.log
123.123.123.123 (123.123.123.123) abc def .....
555.555.555.555 (555.555.555.555) efc bbb .....
```